# Retrieve the checked property of checkboxes in Gridview

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an aspx page wherein there are three placeholders. Now I have checkboxes inside each placeholder. How can I retrieve the checked property of the checkboxes in clientside. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="lblIsActive"  runat="server" CssClass="s_label" />

function Mark_Confirm(elem) 
{
    //var chk=document.getElementById("<%=lblIsActive.ClientID%>");
    var div = document.getElementById('<% = lblIsActive.ClientID %>');    
    var chk = div.getElementsByTagName('input');

    var len = chk.length;      

    if (chk.type == 'checkbox')              
        chk.checked = elem.checked;        

    if(chk.checked==true)
    {
        if (confirm("Do you want to mark the device as lost?")) 
        {
            var confirm_value1 = document.createElement("INPUT");
            confirm_value1.type = "hidden";
            confirm_value1.name = "confirm_value1";
            confirm_value1.value = "Yes";
        } 
        else 
        {
            confirm_value1.value = "No";
        }
    }
    if(chk.checked==false)
    {
        if (confirm("Do you want to mark the device as active?")) 
        {
            var confirm_value2 = document.createElement("INPUT");
            confirm_value2.type = "hidden";
            confirm_value2.name = "confirm_value2";
            confirm_value2.value = "Yes";
        } 
        else 
        {
            confirm_value2.value = "No";
        }
    }
    document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value1);
    document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for this. use the '`checked`'property

```
var isChecked =  document.getElementById('<%=lblIsActive.ClientID%>').checked;
alert(isChecked);
```

or by using jquery you can check the property like this

```
var isChecked = $("#<%=lblIsActive.ClientID%>").is(':checked');
alert(isChecked);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using jQuery;

```
$('.s_label')​​​​​​.each(function(){
  var confirm = $(this).is(':checked');
  alert(confirm);
});;​
```